# tablayout design on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I need the **tabbar background is set white**.  Also I need to have the **selected tab background color set to pink** and the remaining tabs (**unselected** tab) background color set to **blue**. My existing code is shown below.  What do I need to change in it?

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff" >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:background="@drawable/tabicon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**tab_indicator.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_v4" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_v4" />

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" />
</selector>
```

**tab_unselected_v4.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            />

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

**tab_focus.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<!-- Gradient BgColor for listrow Selected -->
<gradient
  android:startColor="#5e8fb7"
  android:centerColor="#5e8fb7"
  android:endColor="#5e8fb7"
  />
 </shape>
```

**tab_selected.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
<gradient
  android:startColor="#5e8fb7"
  android:centerColor="#5e8fb7"
  android:endColor="#5e8fb7"
  />
</shape>
```

**tab_press.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
<gradient
  android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
   />
 </shape>
```

**EDIT:** 
i have added below code.now my background color is change white.but my selected item and unselected item color is not set the needed color.please help me.give me some good solutions.

**tabicon.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="90" 
                 />
                 </shape>
                 </item>
         <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="90"  />

    </shape>
</item>
               </selector>
```

also added below java code:

```
  for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
   {

  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);
    }
   tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);

   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);

     }

   public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
       {
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);
    }
  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator);
    }
      }
```

**EDIT:**

Here i have to set the selected background color and unselected background color is successfully.

Now i wish to need the one implementation here.

The **first tab width is larger than second and third tab width**.how can i do this????
please help me.

Here the dashboard tab is larger than order and customer tab.please help me.how can i design and develop this.
This is my output:
[image: current o/p]

i wish to need the o/p is like below image:

[image: wish to need the o/p]

**EDIT:**

Here i have to use this code on my **style.xml**:

```
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
  <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
  <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
  </style>
   <style name="CustomTabWidgetText" 
   parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
   <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   </style>
```

Afterthat add below line on AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name="MyTabActivity" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Now i have successfully changed my fontsize and color and style on tabhost.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if you put the TabWidget in a LinearLayout which has a white background similar to the following:

```
       <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab_widget"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:background="@drawable/tabicon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Also, for setting the selected and unselected color, you can create an xml with a RelativeLayout whose background is a selector(with different images or colors for selected and unselected states), like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_selected_unselected">


</RelativeLayout>
```

You can then inflate the TabHost.TabSpec indicator by the above xml.

In case you find any difficulty, you can post the same.
All the best!

Comment: please explain clearly.i can't understand.                            here selector_selected_unselected means what you are specify here.

Comment: i got the solution for the my selected item and unselected item background color is changed successfully.

Comment: now i wish to need the first tab width is larger than second and third tab width.hoe can i develop this

Comment: Well the by selector_selected_unselected i meant the selector xml where you specified the selected and unselected colors.

Comment: Also, Can you please post your solution so that it can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first tab width to be larger than the second and third one, you can have a separate xml for it and specify the width accordingly. I am talking about this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_selected_unselected">


</RelativeLayout>
```

While inflating the tab indicator, you can inflate different tab indicators with different xmls.